# How to properly set up an OpenLayers application using a local offline mapping server (mod_tile & Mapnik)?

Tags: openlayers, mapnik

I'm trying to develop a fully offline mapping solution using OpenLayers and [this **very useful** guide](https://switch2osm.github.io/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-20-04-lts/). With it, was able to successfully build a map server. I set it up on a virtual machine, running *Ubuntu Server 20.04*. By following [the "second part"](https://switch2osm.github.io/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/) of the same guide, I could be sure that the server is functioning properly (on *Ubuntu Desktop 20.04*) since a world map containing only details of Azerbaijan was shown.

In my question I say **properly** because it can be seen the script [here](https://switch2osm.github.io/using-tiles/getting-started-with-openlayers/) contains both *html* **and** *JavaScript*, which I would rather not mix. Also it contains some tags like this:

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/build/ol.js"></script>
```

which **completely defeat the purpose** of an offline mapping solution. *Also* I would like to organize the project code by following the model suggested by OpenLayers  [in this page](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html), which separates the code in many files like in this [project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Kxx.png).
Here's how OpenLayers gets data from my map server, in the `url:` field:

```
layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    // This illustrates a custom tiles source but for using
    // official OpenStreetMap server new ol.source.OSM()
    // instead of new ol.source.XYZ(...) is enough
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
      attributions: [
      ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION,
        'Tiles courtesy of ' +
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">' +
        'OpenStreetMap' +
        '</a>'
      ],
   url: 'http://192.168.56.100/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    })
  })
],
```

Hoping I didn't miss anything important I ask: **how can I properly define the tile layer on OpenLayers in a completely offline manner and using my map server?**

Comment: All the OpenLayers releases https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases have a dist.zip link which can be downloaded so you can host the ol.js and ol.css on your own localhost server.  If you are using modern browsers on your own system you are unlikely to need polyfills.